# Now that the OPEN Government Data Act is law, can we request data for free?

Tags: united-states, data-ownership

*Currently reading [The OPEN Government Data Act is now law](https://www.fedscoop.com/open-government-data-act-law/).*

> Now that the measure is the law of the land, agencies will be called upon to maintain comprehensive data catalogs...

I am pretty sure some sites like the [Delaware Business Search](https://icis.corp.delaware.gov/ecorp/entitysearch/namesearch.aspx) (@ delaware.gov) don't offer free bulk access to their public business listings beyond what their web service provides, I am not fully sure I have asked though. Is it just a matter of asking now?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You generally can request data for free, but keep in mind that the Act does not require *every* set of data to be published or released.

For instance, it applies only to data that is subject to release under the Freedom of Information Act. This means that it has no effect on the Delaware Business Search database, because that data is not controlled by a federal agency, and therefore not subject to FOIA.

There have been requests for bulk access to this data in the past, and as far as I know, they have all been rejected. Given the state's economic reliance on its very sketchy business laws, I would but expect that to change any time soon. You would suddenly have journalists and the like scouring the database making all sorts of connections and uncovering all manner of unsavory activity, and no one in a policy making role wants to have to deal with that.

Comment: I will note I have asked and Delaware said they will provide corporate records for $50 per month going back to 2005, so it's a start. But 2005? So soon.

Comment: @LancePollard Do they actually offer everything for $50 per month of data? That comes to $9000 for everything from the last 15 years. A lot for an individual but cheap for a major newspaper or an NGO with a suitable background.